# Installing Theano on windows for gpu - suspected nvcc version issue

Tags: python, c++, windows, cuda, theano

I have been following [instructions](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html) to set up Theano to use a GPU on Windows.

The issue is I cannot follow these instructions exactly because I have a new graphics card, the GEForce GTX 980M and it only works with cuda 7.0. (The instructions suggest cuda 5.5). Everything works fine except when it gets time to run the GPU then I get an error:

```
nvcc fatal   : Value '2008' is not defined for option 'cl-version'

['nvcc', '-shared', '-O3', '--use-local-env', '--cl-version=2008', '-Xlinker', '/DEBUG', '-D HAVE_ROUND', '-m64', '-Xcompiler', '-DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=bf8d22b192850a85a00263cce1175696,-D NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION,/Zi,/MD', '-Ic:\\scisoft\\theano\\theano\\theano\\sandbox\\cuda', '-IC:\\SciSoft\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include', '-IC:\\SciSoft\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\include', '-o', 'C:\\Users\\Thor\\AppData\\Local\\Theano\\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_70_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64\\cuda_ndarray\\cuda_ndarray.pyd', 'mod.cu', '-LC:\\SciSoft\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\libs', '-LC:\\SciSoft\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\\python-2.7.9.amd64', '-lpython27', '-lcublas', '-lcudart']
```

The version of nvcc I have installed does not have version -2008 (that looks to have been deprecated by the lastest cuda 7.0 version, but 2010 is allowed). 
What is the best way to fix it? Should I hard code it in Theano into the file cuda\nvcc_compiler.py? I tried that and it seems to try to use 2008 version anyway.
Is there a later version of Theano that would use the later nvcc version?

Comment: Also when I was installing cuda 7 it said that it couldn't find visual studio even though I have VS10 installed and had just installed a free version of VS12. Any idea why and how to fix? I installed VS12 to a different path to normal.

Comment: Review the actual supported configurations for CUDA 7 in the [getting started document](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html#system-requirements) and I think this will answer your question about why CUDA 7 didn't find a supported version of VS.  The only "free" version of VS supported by CUDA 7 is VS 2013 community edition.

Comment: Yes thanks, I installed 2013 community and that problem went away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem when trying to install Theano on Win 8.1 64bit with CUDA 7.0., using a GTX 750Ti graphics card. I was able to get it working by following these [instructions](https://my6266blog.wordpress.com/2015/01/21/installing-theano-pylearn2-and-even-gpu-on-windows/).

Comment: Thankyou. That almost worked for me, and did work completely after I read the comment on that page about the different versions of Anaconda. I needed to run the instruction 
"conda install mingw libpython"
Then the gpu ran fine.

Answer (score 5):

For me it started working when I replaced

```
[nvcc]
flags = --use-local-env  --cl-version=2008
```

by

```
[nvcc]
compiler_bindir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin
```

in the .theanorc file.